# jQuery .each() only shows last or first value

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

Many questions like mine on Stack, but I just can't get it to work with those answers.

User picks a province and then picks an available date from flatpickr calendar. The available dates come from JSON array and need to be inserted in the config as `enable: ["2021-08-05","2021-05-03", etc.].` However, I only get the first or with some tweaks last available date from the JSON array. What am I doing wrong and how to solve it with commas in between like documentation requires.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
      $('select[name="provincie"]').on('change', function() {
        var provincie_id = $(this).val();

        if (provincie_id) {
          $.ajax({
            url: 'link/' + provincie_id,
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data) { //see data below
              var html = [""]

              $.each(data, function(key, value) {
                config = {
                  inline: true,
                  altInput: true,
                  dateFormat: "Y-m-d",
                  enable: [
                    html += [value]
                  ],
                }
              });

              flatpickr("input[type=datepick]", config);
            }
          });

        } else {
          $('select[name="datum"]').empty();
        }
      });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

```
{"1":"2021-09-27","2":"2021-09-28","3":"2021-09-29","4":"2021-09-30"} //This is the data from JSON for a particular province
```

Tried using .append() to no avail

Comment: Please seek [ask]. I'd remove the ajax call from this demo, mockup an array, and show us how it actually works in a functioning snippet.

Comment: `var html = [""]` and `html += [value]` makes no sense. What exactly do you think that is doing? If you are trying to build an array, you should be using map()

Comment: You never use the `html` variable.

Comment: Each time through the loop you reassign `config`. After the loop is done, it contains the last value.

Comment: Especially `[ html += [ value ] ]`… What do you think this is doing?

Comment: To get a real answer, you need to show us what `data` is exactly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use `$.each()`. You can use `Object.values()` to get the values of all the object properties, and use that as the `enable:` property.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('select[name="provincie"]').on('change', function() {
    var provincie_id = $(this).val();
    if (provincie_id) {
      $.ajax({
        url: 'link/' + provincie_id,
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
          config = {
            inline: true,
            altInput: true,
            dateFormat: "Y-m-d",
            enable: Object.values(data),
          };
          flatpickr("input[type=datepick]", config);
        }
      });
    } else {
      $('select[name="datum"]').empty();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Flatpickr gives error: TypeError: e.slice is not a function. (In 'e.slice()', 'e.slice' is undefined

Comment: Are you sure the API is returning an array of strings?

Comment: Can you add a sample of the JSON response to the question?

Comment: Yes, I added it: {"1":"2021-09-27","2":"2021-09-28","3":"2021-09-29","4":"2021-09-30"} is the JSON response

Comment: That's an object, not an array.

Comment: Use `Object.values()` to get the values as an array.

Comment: Thank you! It's all new to me, but object.values() did it!

Answer (score 0):

Now that you shown data returned from the api, it is possible to do this no looping. You have an object and you just want the values of the object. So you can use `Object.values()`

```
        success: function(data) { //see data below
          var config = {
              inline: true,
              altInput: true,
              dateFormat: "Y-m-d",
              enable: Object.values(data),
            }
          });

          flatpickr("input[type=datepick]", config);
        }
```

Comment: Thank you. Only problem is that upon change of the province selector, the calendar doesn't update with the new dates.